# Converting a Join Query into a Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I'm attempting to write a sub query that wold accomplish the same results as the join query shown below.

```
SELECT Department_to_major.DNAME
FROM Department_to_major
INNER JOIN Course
ON Department_to_major.Dcode = Course.OFFERING_DEPT
WHERE Course.COURSE_NAME LIKE '%INTRO%'
GROUP BY Department_to_major.DNAME
```

However each attempt has produced errors.

Is there a way to write this as a sub query?

Comment: But why? sub queries are far less efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query. I am assuming that you have used "GROUP BY" clause to make  DNAME field unique.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DNAME)
FROM Department_to_major
WHERE Dcode IN (SELECT OFFERING_DEPT
            FROM Course
            WHERE COURSE_NAME LIKE '%INTRO%');
```

Comment: Yes, in the first query before adding the GROUP BY clause there would be multiple rows of the same Department name appearing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT DNAME FROM Department_to_major WHERE
Dcode IN (SELECT OFFERING_DEPT FROM Course
WHERE COURSE_NAME LIKE '%INTRO%')
```

You have used GROUP BY clause, but there is no any aggregate function in the query.

Comment: The query is producing the results I was expecting/hoping it would.  Namely to list all department names that have intro courses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dm.DNAME
FROM Department_to_major dm
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Course c
              WHERE dm.Dcode = c.OFFERING_DEPT AND
                    c.COURSE_NAME LIKE '%INTRO%'
             );
```

I assume the `GROUP BY` is to prevent duplicates in the output; `SELECT DISTINCT` does the same thing.

That said, storing the department code *and* name in `Department_to_major` is not a good data structure, because the department name is (presumably) repeated multiple times.  I would expect you to have just a `Departments` table, with one row per department.

Then the query would look like:

```
SELECT d.DNAME
FROM Departments d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Course c
              WHERE d.Dcode = c.OFFERING_DEPT AND
                    c.COURSE_NAME LIKE '%INTRO%'
             );
```

And the `SELECT DISTINCT`/`GROUP BY` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  You are correct, there is a separate table for Department.  The query works without issue.